# Why this POST request doesn't work?

Tags: c#, http-post

I wanted to make a post request in this website: http://www.prezup.info/index.php?page=films in order to make a research. However when I do the post request, the result is not what I expected ( results of the research ), but the main page.

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my request?

Here is the code: date is the post request arg and url the url

```
public string POST()
  {
       string data = "motcle=terminator&ok.x=17&ok.y=16";
        string Reponse = String.Empty;
        string contenttype = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        string useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; fr; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100722 Firefox/3.6.8 ( .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0E)";
        string host = "www.prezup.info";
        string url = "http://www.prezup.info/index.php?page=films";
        string method = "POST";

        StreamWriter Sw = null; // Pour écrire les données
        StreamReader Sr = null; // Pour lire les données
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest Req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            Req.Method = method; // POST ou GET
            Req.Host = host;
            Req.KeepAlive = true;
            Req.UserAgent = useragent;
            Req.CookieContainer = cookieJar;

            ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] byte1 = encoding.GetBytes(data);
            Req.ContentType = contenttype;
            Req.ContentLength = byte1.Length; // La longueur des données
            Stream newStream = Req.GetRequestStream();
            newStream.Write(byte1, 0, byte1.Length);
            newStream.Close();

            Sr = new StreamReader(((HttpWebResponse)Req.GetResponse()).GetResponseStream());
            Reponse = Sr.ReadToEnd(); // On choppe la réponse
            int cookieCount = cookieJar.Count;
            Sr.Close(); // Et on ferme
            Sw = null;
        }
        catch (Exception e) // En cas d'exception
        {
            if (Sw != null) // Si le flux est ouvert, on le ferme
                Sw.Close();
            if (Sr != null)
                Sr.Close();

            Reponse = e.Message;
        }
        return Reponse;
    }
```

Comment: Not the answer to your question. 1. Did you know that you are not even using that StreamWriter object? 2. Dispose disposable objects, and [do it elegantly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) by using the `using` statement.

Comment: It should work. What kind of error do you receive?

Comment: if the response is not what you expect, then you have to research that whether the web site is sending something else to the browers and a different response to you. use wireshark to see what response usually comes. you are only going to get what the website is sending, not what you think you should get

Comment: You are right but in fact, i thought there were a problem with "&ok.x=17&ok.y=16" . I didn't know what it exactly was. I am totally fault. Thank you for the tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That form makes a POST request to `http://www.prezup.info/index.php?page=films&action=list`, so your URL is incorrect. Change:

```
string url = "http://www.prezup.info/index.php?page=films";
```

To

```
string url = "http://www.prezup.info/index.php?page=films&action=list";
```

And it will work.